# How can I efficiently request part of a rasterstack in R

Tags: r, raster

When I read in very large tiff file as follows

```
 r = stack( 'tiffile.tif')
```

then I would like to request a small portion of it by

```
r_part = r[1:100, 1:100, ]
```

I would expect to find r_part to be a 3D rasterstack. However it turns out to be a a matrix with dimension widht*height and the number of channels.

How can I extract a 3D rasterstack in this manner?

Comment: When you index a `raster` object with square brackets, your indexing the values and therefore will get a value matrix in return. To get a `raster` object returned, look at `raster::crop` which can be used with row/column indices

Answer (score 1):

You could use *`extent(rasterObject, rowstart, rowend, colstart, colend)`*  to create an extent object based on rows and columns. Thus you do not have to convert your whole raster to a matrix first (as done with `[,]`) which might exceed your memory when working with large files.

```
library(raster)
r <- stack("tiffile.tif")
r_part <- crop(r, extent(r, 1, 100, 1, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Example data (from `?stack`!)

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
```

You can use `drop=FALSE`

```
s1 <- s[20:25, 20:25, drop=FALSE]
```

Or (as loki suggests) create an `Extent` and then use `crop`

```
e <- extent(s, 20, 25, 20, 25)
s2 <- crop(s, e)
```